# Does HTML5 support Unicode in passwords?

Tags: html, unicode, hash, passwords

We are in 2013, and because i have found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1825824/1505086), I've made a [simple application where users can use a visual keyboard](https://github.com/abdelouahabb/essog), and a font that supports unicode ([deja vu](http://dejavu-fonts.org/)) which i have modified using [fontforge](http://fontforge.org/) to make it smaller and let only caracters that users know (arabic, french, tifinagh (north Africa language)) to make it easy to send in on the network, so if users will make passwords using unicode then, the password will be hard to crack.

Does HTML5 go rid of that bug of Unicode and passwords?

Comment: HTML5 has nothing to do with HTTP basic authentication.  What are you asking about?

Comment: the browsers had a bug dealing with basic authentication, this is why some systems force to use only ASCII

Comment: But that has nothing to do with HTML5, and nothing to do with custom fonts.  What are you asking about?

Comment: what i mean is: does the latest browsers corrected the bug of unicode and basic authentication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug you're talking about affects HTTP basic authenication, in which the browser prompts for credentials and passes them as HTTP headers.

Your application does not use basic authentication; instead, it uses a `<form>` tag to POST login info to the server.

`<form>`s do support Unicode properly.

Comment: so that bug dident talk about the form submission using post? but only a simple basic authentication?