# Google Chrome / macOS: Password field won't accept non-ASCII characters

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, passwords, usability

> ### Update
>
> Apparently this is an unresolved issue with the OS X version of Google Chrome. [It was first reported over seven years ago.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=78048) If you happen to find yourself needing to enter a password containing non-ASCII characters, then here are your options:
>
> - Type in the password somewhere else and transfer it to the password field via the clipboard.
> - Use the developer tools to change the input type from `password` to `text`.
> - Use a different browser

---

Are there any rules about the characters that can be entered into a password field? I've been experimenting with Chrome on a Mac and it looks like I can only enter "special" characters if they can be produced with a single keypress (not including modifier keys like <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>).

For example, I can enter a copyright symbol (©) with a single keypress (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>), but the letter "o" with an umlaut (ö) requires two (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> followed by <kbd>O</kbd>). In the latter case, the umlaut won't appear in the password. In Windows, it seems that these characters are obtained by typing in magic numbers while pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, so there are probably cross-platform differences in this behaviour. There may also be cross-browser differences.

The reason I'm asking is because I want to implement a sign-up form with a password entry field that can be switched from `type="password"` to `type="text"`. This allows the user to check the contents of the field (assuming it's safe to do so), and allows me to use a random password generator to pre-fill this field with something that the user can then copy into the confirmation field. But by doing so, I'm changing the set of characters that this field accepts. This is obviously undesirable; if I choose `Röntgen` as a password, for example, I will never be able to log in (unless the log-in form is also switchable).

So what's the best approach here? I don't want to ban special characters altogether, but restricting everyone to printable ASCII looks like the easiest option.

To illustrate the issue, here's a form with two password fields. One field can be switched to an ordinary text input. Click the button to reveal the contents of the two fields.

```js
function reveal() {
  if ($('#p1').attr('type') == 'password') {
    $('#p1').attr('type', 'text');
    $('#r').html('(Hide)');
  }
  else {
    $('#p1').attr('type', 'password');
    $('#r').html('(Reveal)');
  }
}

function show_passwords() {
  $('#out1').html($('#p1').val());
  $('#out2').html($('#p2').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form onsubmit="return false;">
    <p><label>Password:<br><input type="password" id="p1" name="p1" size="20"></label>
    <small><a id="r" href="#" onclick="reveal()">(Reveal)</a></small></p>
    <p><label>Confirm password:<br><input type="password" id="p2" name="p2" size="20"></label></p>
    <p><button onclick="show_passwords(); return false">Show password field contents</button></p>
  </form>
</div>
<table style="min-width:20em; border: 1px solid #bbb">
  <tr><td style="width:8em">Password:</td><td id="out1"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Password confirm:</td><td id="out2"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I believe it's got to do with the clients accepted character range (ie if their client only handles UTF-8 they can' only input UTF 8)

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem since I cannot reproduce any similar on my side (Firefox on Win10 with Spanish keyboard layout) but it feels like a bug or limitation on Apple/Google side rather than something intentional in HTML, JavaScript or the DOM. When you say "won't appear in the password", what do you get instead? Nothing at all? Is your application using a fully Unicode compatible encoding such as UTF-8?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Like I said, I just get the "o" without the umlaut. I don't understand what you mean by Unicode compatibility. The snippet I provided is running from a Stack Overflow server. Stack Overflow uses UTF-8 everywhere. So do I. I'm sure Chrome is compatible with UTF-8. I would imagine all current web browsers are. None of this explains the difference in behaviour between text input and password input fields. Maybe it's just an OS X issue then?

Comment: Sorry, some times questions include stack snippets that don't reproduce the issue thus my remark.

Comment: **Update:** It seems that this problem only occurs in Google Chrome. With Firefox and Safari, there seem to be no problems entering non-ASCII characters (as long as I don't switch to a non-Western input method like Japanese, that is). Is anyone able to test the behaviour of Chrome on other platforms?

Comment: Chrome does not seem to exhibit this behaviour either in my copy of Windows 10 (Spanish layout).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks for checking. Apparently this is an old bug in the Mac version of Chrome that never got fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original author of the report on the chromium bugtrack here. I was told to open the same issue on the [webkit's bugtraq](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57817) (back then Chrome ran on webkit) and a webkit dev told me that Cocoa (OSX UI framework) does not allow non-ASCII characters on password fields (and I've already found that issue, my OSX password is not as challenging as my online services passwords) and that the Webkit tries hard to mimic native behavior. So the problem is not your browser but OSX itself.

To be fair, when Chrome switched to Blink, there was a new message on the bugtrack:

> This is still an issue.
>   On the original WebKit bug, it was "decided" that allowing dead key input in password controls is not an ideal 
>   solution, and WebKit should strive to follow Cocoa's behavior.
>
> As it stands now, Blink fails in both manners: dead keys do not behave as they do in text fields, and they do 
>   not follow NSSecureTextField's behavior either (i.e. behaving a though the key is not a dead key).
>
> WebKit 601.2.7 in Safari 9.0.1 behaves as expected. Should Blink follow platform behavior as well, or would 
>   supporting dead keys in password fields be preferred?

But time has passed and nothing changed so far...

I just use Firefox which does not follow Cocoa's limitation and allows any characater on a password field.

If you don't want to force your users, just skip non ASCII characters from your generated password.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Just for the record, I'm not *generating* non-ASCII passwords, it's just that once the password input field has been changed to text, the user can change it to anything at all. I tried again with Safari after reading your answer and found that its behaviour depends on the keyboard setting. With the Japanese Romaji keyboard selected, it works just fine, but with the US keyboard, Alt-U is blocked with an alert sound. In both cases, I can still enter non-ASCII characters like µ and © (Alt-M and Alt-G), so if Apple has a UI standard, they haven't really stuck to it properly.

Comment: Well, then I guess you just have to expect your users to know this limitation, after all they use a OSX machine and should know its tricks :-)

Comment: Ha. I've been using Macs for years, and this is the first time I've encountered this particular quirk. Anyway, I'm going to follow Joey's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1797777/1679849) and just put up a warning message when a user types a non-ASCII character into a password field.